# Proper way to find the SHA-1 hash of two big integers and return it as a string

Tags: java, math, hash

I would like to hash two BigIntegers in Java with the MessageDigest class.

So far I have the following code

```
// SHA(v concantenated with n) 
public void calculateProversCertificate(BigInteger v, BigInteger n)
{
    MessageDigest md;
    try 
    {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(v.toByteArray());
        md.update(n.toByteArray());
        byte[] byteData = md.digest();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.length; i++) 
        {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xFF) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }
        String hash = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("Certificate:" + hash);
    } 
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Could not create SHA MessageDigest class");
    }
}
```

The code I have there is works to calculate a hash but it is not the proper length when printed as a string. I used this code to create "cookies" from user passwords and I would like to adapt it to find the hash of two BigIntegers. I am specifically not sure about the for loop and how it works. I assume it is rejoining the Byte[] into something that can be represented as a string. Though this is a little over my head on how it does this.

Could someone explain the idea behind the loop, and how it is building the string? Also how I might adapt it to produce an output like the example below?

Basically I am looking for output something like this

```
 1tdgsp8bs0gk72dbvpu0be33tv2dobimc4mg07d209401mrhbe23qe1tdh7jcd78so46ffet20lqemlakv4mfvbk6fjp9a2th9bhb2
```

But I am getting something like this (Produced by the print statement in the code)

```
9aa1770b83257b2c7b2a6fb9684253930781c0cf
```

And example V and N (Produced by BigInteger.toString();)

```
V: 1678202601632665039275603893340186995409970283833828187403506666684692322312620073622777464636561237395218125410336245265888297965169878433803688272535099
N: 8449118772240198089422438092628650298318511756191052993769148184590886001852753186246607550316706472668220614311553576373631078947139889888957411418229019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That loop looks like it's a convoluted way of turning a byte array into a hexadecimal string. It takes each byte value, applies a hideous function to turn it into two hex characters, and appends them to a `StringBuilder`.

I don't know why the author didn't just use `Integer.toHexString`, or, even better, `String.format` inside the loop. Either of those would be much easier than what you have now.

Note that `byteData[i] & 0xFF` does nothing (except promote to `int`, which you don't need since byte values can auto-promote to int). `byteData[i]` is a `byte`, and executing `& 0xFF` on a byte value is a no-op.

Anyway, this code appears to be generating the right output. SHA-1 generates a 160-bit hash, and that looks like a 40-character hex string. Hex encodes 4 bits per character, so that seems to be a valid encoding of the hash value (40 characters * 4 bits per character = 160 bits in the hash)

> Basically I am looking for output something like this
>   1tdgsp8bs0gk72dbvpu0be33tv2dobimc4mg07d209401mrhbe23qe1tdh7jcd78so46ffet20lqemlakv4mfvbk6fjp9a2th9bhb2

Where did you get that string from? Why do you expect your hash output to look like that?

Incidentally, I hope you are not really implementing your own certificate check. Crypto code is notoriously difficult to get right so you should be using an existing library. If you roll your own crypto you *will* have a vulnerability (probably many vulnerabilities).

Comment: This is for a cryptography class, thus why we are trying to implement these by ourselves. It is, as you said, hideous. // That string is a given certificate from a certificate authority (teachers server), I am trying to calculate a certificate from a given users public key (V and N; modulus and exponent), and verify it by decomposing a users signed certificate (signed by the authorities public modulus). Thus, I would figure the SHA-1 hash of V concatenated with N would produce a longer String. // I am lost in the numbers yet again.

Comment: Hashes turn an arbitrary set of input bytes into a fixed length string, so `SHA1(new byte[1])` produces the same amount of output as `SHA1(new byte[129000])`. You will always get 160 bytes out no matter what the input is.

Comment: I'm glad to hear this is for a crypto class. I've seen many people disastrously try to implement their own crypto in real systems, so that's why I wanted to warn you off if that's what you were attempting.